# MySQLi - Select previous result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to select previous value using php and mysqli.
How can I select that?

Table1

---

```
|ID__|__VALUE__|
|1 --|--Rami--|
|2 --|--Sami--|
|3 --|--John--|
|4 --|--Jack--|
|5 --|--Mark--|
```

PHP CODE

```
    //THIS GETTING 'JOHN'
    $sql0 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = '3' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql0))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
        }

    //THIS GETTING 'JACK'
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table1` LIMIT  $id, 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
          {
              $id = $row['id'];
          }
```

This my php code trying get 'Sami' VALUE. Bad code but that what I tried!

```
 //THIS GETTING 'SAMI'
 $sql2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table1` LIMIT  $id, -1");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
      {
           $id = $row['id'];               
      }
```

Comment: I'm trying to make NEXT(JACK) and PREVIOUS(SAMI) links on page where showing 'JOHN' value

Comment: oops, I thought this was about cascading `<select>`s, but looking at it now, there are no selects.

Comment: `LIMIT N,M` syntax at least accept ONLY POSITIVE values :-) and you are trying to achive something simple with something very unclear and overcomplicated. explain us what is your expected result, and we will help you to simlify your code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that your ids are ordered.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id > $id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

This will select the 1st row (`LIMIT 1`) where `id > $id`, so in plain words: The first row after the row with `$id`. Ther `ORDER BY` is necessary, so the limit works properly (you get all rows in ascending order)

Respectively

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

will get the previous row to `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your sql-query

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE id=$id-1");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
      {
           $id = $row['id'];               
      }
```

Comment: Once a row has been deleted, this won't work anymore. Say you have following ids 1, 3, 5 - even though 5 comes after 3, your query wouldn't find it

Comment: Thanks to replay. But I don't prefer this way because may this id will deleted in future how to getting previous id than!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the last_insert_id() this is will give the last inserted value in that perticular table

Comment: Thanks to replay. I have **no insert** here to use `last_insert_id()` ! its select only!

Comment: Dear Rami, In select query also we can use this function.